# Provide dynamic arguments to `terminal.integrated.profiles.*`

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to pass a hash value of `${cwd}` to invoke `tmux new -A -s` in an integrated terminal profile.

I tried various forms of `"$(…)"`, like so:

```
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.osx": {
        "tmux": {
            "path": "/usr/local/bin/tmux",
            "args": [
                "new",
                "-A",
                "-s",
                "$(md5sum <<<${cwd} | cut -d ' ' -f 1)"
            ]
        },
    },
```

When this profile is invoked, a `tmux` session does start, but its name is the literal `$(md5sum <<</Users/USER/PATH/TO/CWD | cut -d ' ' -f 1)`, which is hard to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest to try writing a wrapper script for that command and use that wrapper script in the `path` property. You'll probably need to give your wrapper script a shebang for the shell it needs. Also, in case you need it, [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference)'s the VS Code variable reference.

Answer (score 1):

Using @starball's suggestion, I wrote a simple wrapper:

```bash
#! /bin/zsh
exec tmux new -A -s $(md5sum <<<$1 | cut -d ' ' -f 1)
```

and its invocation via `settings.json`:

```json
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.osx": {
        "tmux": {
            "path": "${userHome}/local/bin/tmux-vscode",
            "args": [
                "${cwd}"
            ]
        },
    },
```

Now I have:

```
$ tmux ls
231309d1a2b2cc0f38adf8e95440c11b: 1 windows (created Mon Nov  6 08:56:18 2023) (attached)
cc0c79461a3bc1ffe210da0d763d93b3: 1 windows (created Mon Nov  6 08:54:23 2023) (attached)
```